# How to prepare data outputted from sql in php to run through the PHP machine learning Library

Tags: php, arrays, machine-learning, prepared-statement

I am playing around with the LeastSquares regression algorithm from the PHP ML library. I can successfully run the code with the example given but when I try to run data from my database I get a blank screen returned and no error logs on the server.

Here is the working example php file from the ML library:

```
$samples = [[50000, 2017], [40000, 2015], [75000, 2014], [30000, 2016]];   
$targets = [15000,13000,14500,14000];

regression = new LeastSquares();
$regression->train($samples, $targets);

echo $regression->predict([60000, 2015]);
// returns 4094.82
```

Here is myScript

```
$sql = "SELECT price, mileage, year From table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        // The output I am looking for is [[mileage, year],[mileage, year]..] & [price, price,..]

        $mileage = $row['mileage'];

        $year = $row['year'];
   
        $price = $row['price'];

    }
}


regression = new LeastSquares();
$regression->train($samples, $targets);

echo $regression->predict([60000, 2015]);
```

I am trying to recreate the $samples and $targets variables with values from my DB table but I am not preparing it correctly.I tried preg_replace to create a comma separated string but that didnt work, I suspect it's because it's a string and not integer values but Im not exactly sure. I wrote the example shown so might be a syntax error but im just trying to figure out the correct way to prepare the array values like the ML library gives.

When I do

```
var_dump($samples);

var_dump($targets);
```

I get

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(50000) [1]=> int(2017) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(40000) [1]=> int(2015) } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(75000) [1]=> int(2014) } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(30000) [1]=> int(2016) } }


array(4) { [0]=> int(15000) [1]=> int(13000) [2]=> int(14500) [3]=> int(14000) }
```

So that would be what I am trying to achieve with my SQL output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to push the values you are reading from the database into the `$samples` and `$targets` arrays in your loop. It may also be necessary to convert them to integers, I've included that code too.

```
$sql = "SELECT price, mileage, year From table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$samples = array();
$targets = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $mileage = (int)$row['mileage'];
        $year = (int)$row['year'];
        $samples[] = array($mileage, $year);
        $price = (int)$row['price'];
        $targets[] = array($price);
    }
}
```

Note that without an `else` clause, the `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` clause serves no useful purpose in this code as the `while` loop will not do anything if `$result->num_rows == 0` (i.e. there are no rows in the result set).

Comment: Thank you, Im testing it now but Im getting 0 values from the DB so not sure whats going on.. I will be back in a minute once I can deduce my issue here. The mileage column in the DB is the only string type. year and price are already int if that makes a difference

Comment: im getting values, they are just (0) to clarify

Comment: @RyanD if the values are `int` you won't need to convert them, but the driver may return them as strings even if they are integers. You should check that just in case.

Comment: Works great, I had and error in my sql code thats why I was getting 0. Thanks for the help and understanding! Cheers

Comment: @RyanD no worries - I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Yeah I didnt need to add the (int)$row but I think it is a good way to protect from characters that could potentially be passed from the DB

Comment: @Dharman you are correct. I generally don't like to change OPs code any more than necessary to resolve their issue in case it doesn't represent the true code they are using (e.g. there might be an `else` clause that OP has left out because it has no effect on this functionality). I've made a note about it though.

Comment: @Dharman If there are serious issues with OPs code or it's horribly inefficient, I will do the same. But for smaller changes like this I prefer not to make any more changes than necessary so that OP can get their existing code running more rapidly. Addition of comments such as the poiint you made about the `if` can then point OP at ways to improve their own code.

Comment: @Dharman as you say, it's a matter of preference - which we could fight about for years :-). I've added a comment to the answer because you made a good point and it definitely improves the answer.